# Is it possible to import the Gvc typelib outside of the Gnome Shell environment?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs, gobject-introspection

I'd like to use Gvc ([libgnome-volume-control](https://github.com/GNOME/libgnome-volume-control)) [as used in Gnome Shell](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/status/volume.js) GIR in GJS, but can't find a way to access it except within the Gnome Shell environment (eg. a Gnome Shell extension). Actually, I can't even figure out where it is. Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

In line with Philip Withnall's comment (about a hacky workaround), I have found it's possible to import like so:

```
const GIRepository = imports.gi.GIRepository;
GIRepository.Repository.prepend_search_path("/usr/lib/gnome-shell");
GIRepository.Repository.prepend_library_path("/usr/lib/gnome-shell");
const Gvc = imports.gi.Gvc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

libgnome-volume-control is [currently only meant to be used as a submodule](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgnome-volume-control/tree/meson.build#n6). gnome-shell lists it in its [`.gitmodules` file](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/.gitmodules?h=gnome-3-26) to import the code, and then in [`meson.build`](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/meson.build?h=gnome-3-26#n189) to build it.

It should be possible to use libgnome-volume-control in your project similarly.

(I determined this using `git grep -i gvc` on the gnome-shell code.)

Comment: Ah, unfortunately my project is a GJS (only) shell extension, just with a GJS daemon running outside the Shell environment (since shell extensions are disabled on "session-mode" changes). Still answers my question though, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Can you not compile libgvc as a submodule and ship the `.so` and `.typelib` privately alongside your daemon?

Comment: I think that would be architecture dependant no? Even if not, the extent of transparency in the extensions.gnome.org review process is generally "do work"->"reject/accept". I wonder if I could file a bug about shipping it separately since that's what Cinnamon/Mint seems to do (gir1.2-cvc-1.0 in ubuntu repos), or if there's a good reason it's submodule-only.

Comment: It would indeed be architecture-dependent. Sorry, I didn’t realise you were shipping everything inside the shell extension archive. You might be able to do some hackery by changing the `GI_TYPELIB_PATH` to include gnome-shell’s private typelib directory (which contains the libgvc typelib — look at what files your distribution’s gnome-shell package installs) so you can include it from your extension. However, that is horrifically hacky. I suggest that in any case you get in touch with Florian Müllner and ask him about making libgvc public. He’s on IRC most of the time.

Comment: Well, will be good to me also, if the library can be public. I hate to see something that can be shared just hided.