# How can I test my GNOME Shell extension without risk of crashing the shell?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

During development, I introduced an error to my extension that causes `gnome-shell` to crash upon trying to load the extension with the following rather broadly phrased error message:

```
Execution of main.js threw exception: JS_EvaluateScript() failed
```

It would be nice to be able to test an extension while

- getting descriptive error messages that tell me the actual location of an error
- not risk crashing the whole shell

Is this possible?

---

I already searched through the `gnome-shell` and `gjs` repos to try and find a way to improve the error message. I found three call sites that emit an error with prefix `Execution of main.js threw exception:` but I could not find the actual call to `JS_EvaluateScript` in GJS.

---

I also tried running my extension with `gjs` like this:

```
gjs -I /usr/lib/gnome-shell extension.js
```

But `gjs` complains about

```
Typelib file for namespace 'St' (any version) not found @extension.js:3:7
```

although `St-1.0.typelib` is indeed located in `/usr/lib/gnome-shell`

---

I know that I can use LookingGlass to evaluate some JS strings.

---

I know that the error was caused by calling into native code (`St`) with invalid arguments.

Comment: If you are worried about crashing shell, you could test your extension in shell running in separate X server, eg. Xnest or Xephyr. Or whatever wayland provides...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JS_EvaluateScript` in that error message is outdated, and not particularly helpful. It will be improved in the upcoming GNOME 3.28.

The code you are looking for (with the improved error message) is [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/blob/master/gjs/context.cpp#L795-821) and you can see there is a call to `gjs_log_exception()` right after setting the error that is returned to GNOME Shell. You should be able to find that exception in the system journal (`sudo journalctl -xb`), even on your current version of GNOME.

There's always a risk of crashing the shell, since native code may crash if you give it wrong input. We aim to prevent crashes in GJS itself assuming native code is well-behaved. Once you isolate the problem, if it seems like something GJS could prevent, please make a bug report at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs.

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46674935/is-it-possible-to-import-the-gvc-typelib-outside-of-the-gnome-shell-environment?rq=1) might help to test your extension in a separate process, if you put the following code at the top of your file before you import `St`:

```
const GIRepository = imports.gi.GIRepository;
GIRepository.Repository.prepend_search_path("/usr/lib/gnome-shell");
GIRepository.Repository.prepend_library_path("/usr/lib/gnome-shell");
```

However, it depends on what you are doing in your extension. Many extensions modify parts of GNOME Shell, and so if you run outside of GNOME Shell then they won't work.

Comment: FTR, on RedHat-based systems that should be `/usr/lib64/gnome-shell` instead. You'll also need to call them both again with `/usr/lib[64]/mutter-12` or similar, for the `Meta` typelib that `St` depends on.

Comment: That's still unlikely to get you anywhere, as you won't have any of the GNOME Shell JS. _However_, that can be extracted from `/usr/lib[64]/gnome-shell/libshell-*.so` using `gresource` (`gresource list` for a directory, repeated `gresource extract` runs to laboriously dump out one path at a time to stdout). _Then_ you can set the directory you extracted the resource tree into as an import path with `gjs -I /path/to/org/gnome/shell/`. (Make sure it has subdirs like `ui/` and `misc/`, where `imports.ui` and `imports.misc` live.) And **_now_** maybe you're getting somewhere.